# python pygame change the aliens direction

Tags: python

i trying to check the alien whether it is touch the screen edge, if touched then move down and change the direction.

when i writing the codes and run it, only one row of the alien will do it , another row of the alien always on the same row move right and left.

I use  these two method to implements the function, but may some wrong in it.

```
def ck_edge(setting,aliens):
     for alien in aliens.sprites():
         if alien.x > setting.w:
             alien.change_direction()
             break
         if alien.x < 0:
             alien.change_direction()
             break
 def change_direction(self):
        self.rect.y +=1
        self.direction *= -1
```

what cause?

here's the codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import pygame as p
class Setting():
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.w=width
        self.h=height
        self.flag=p.RESIZABLE
        self.screen=p.display.set_mode((self.w,self.h),self.flag)
        p.display.set_caption("Muhaha")


class Alien(p.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pic=p.image.load("../image/ship.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.image=p.transform.smoothscale(pic,(100,100))
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.rect.x=(self.rect.width)
        self.speed=1
        self.direction = 1
    def create(self,setting,aliens):
        spacex=setting.w-(self.rect.x)*2
        spacey=(setting.h)/2-self.rect.y
        alien_number=int(spacex/(2*(self.rect.width)))
        alien_row=int(spacey/(2*(self.rect.height)))
        for row in range(alien_row):
           for number in range(alien_number):
               alien=Alien()
               alien.x=alien.rect.x+2*alien.rect.width*number
               alien.rect.x=alien.x
               alien.rect.y=alien.rect.y+2*alien.rect.height*row
               aliens.add(alien)
    def ck_edge(setting,aliens):
       for alien in aliens.sprites():
           if alien.x > setting.w:
               alien.change_direction()
               break
           elif alien.x < 0:
               alien.change_direction()
               break

    def change_direction(self):
        self.rect.y +=1
        self.direction *= -1

    def update(self):
        self.x += (self.speed*self.direction)
        self.rect.x =self.x
    def position(setting,aliens):
        Alien.ck_edge(setting,aliens)
        aliens.update()
    def blit(setting,aliens):
        aliens.draw(setting.screen)

def game():
    p.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)
    alien=Alien()
    aliens=p.sprite.Group()
    alien.create(setting,aliens)
    while True:
         for event in p.event.get():
             if event.type == p.QUIT:
                 sys.exit()
         setting.screen.fill((255,0,0))
         Alien.blit(setting,aliens)
         Alien.position(setting,aliens)
         p.display.flip()
game()
```

Comment: Because you `break` out of the loop after the first collision. Remove the `break`s.

Comment: Thanks!! it worked